# Laravel eloquent relationship (one-to-one)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

Can you please help me with this error, I am using laravel version 5.2.*. I have setup a One-to-One relation between a student and an application. Please see the code below.

**Student Model:**

```
public function application() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Application');
}
```

**Application Model:**

```
public function student() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Student');
}
```

The database is correctly setup, I have a `student_id` FK in the Applications table. However, I am still getting the following error. What am I doing wrong, what did I miss? this worked before, it just broke all of a sudden.

> BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2146: Call to undefined
>   method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::applications()

I get the error when I try to insert into the applications table, i.e. When trying to create an application for the student with the code below.

```
$student = new Student;
//There's code to insert into the students table here
$application = new Application([
            'academic_year_id' => $year,
            'ref_no' => Application::getReferenceNumber($year)->Ref_no,
            'certificate_id' => 1, //This will remain hard coded until the centre starts to offer more than one certificate
            'status' => "PENDING",
            'slug' => str_slug(Application::getReferenceNumber($year)->Ref_no . "" . $academic_year->year)
        ]);
        $student->applications()->save($application); //Insert into the application table
```

Comment: `$student->applications()->save($application);` will be `$student->application()->save($application);` I think

Comment: Yes, thank you.. How did I miss that.. I swear I looked at that over and over again, why couldn't I see the S

Comment: @Md.SahadatHossain Howdy, since your comment is the solution can you post it as an answer and have Richard accept it for the purpose of closing the question and benefiting the community. Thanks

Comment: @ihatehandles post an answer. Thank you for your concern. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Student` model your function name is `application` not `applications`. So change your code

```
$student->application()->save($application);
```

instead of

```
$student->applications()->save($application);
```